# Junit test reports listed twice due to symlinks

Tags: jenkins, junit

I face this problem: the "real" directories that contain Junit test results in my project have also an equivalent symlink.

for example:

- myproject/app1/test/test1_report.xml
- myproject/app1/test/test2_report.xml
- myproject/app1-1.4.8 -> symlink to app1

In Jenkins job configuration, I've set "**/test*report.xml" as the Test report XMLs path.

The result is that each test report is listed twice at the end of the build as symlinks are followed by Jenkins when looking for tests reports.

Is there any way to tell Jenkins not to follow symlinks?